# Metro UI library : Css not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use the [metro UI css](http://metroui.org.ua/) library but I can't figure out why my navbar css is not working.

**Here's my html file code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
<title>TelePrint Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/teleprintblog/assets/css/metro-bootstrap.css">
    <script src="http://localhost/teleprintblog/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/teleprintblog/assets/js/metro.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navigation-bar dark fixed">
<nav class="navigation-bar-content">
    <div class="element">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">METRO UI CSS</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">File Open</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Print...</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Exit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <span class="element-divider"></span>
    <a class="element brand" href="#"><span class="icon-spin"></span></a>
    <a class="element brand" href="#"><span class="icon-printer"></span></a>
    <span class="element-divider"></span>

    <div class="element input-element">
        <form>
            <div class="input-control text">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                <button class="btn-search"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="element place-right">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
            <span class="icon-cog"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu place-right" data-role="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Buy Now</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="element-divider place-right"></span>
    <a class="element place-right" href="#"><span class="icon-locked-2"></span></a>
    <span class="element-divider place-right"></span>
    <button class="element image-button image-left place-right">
        Sergey Pimenov
        <img src="images/211858_100001930891748_287895609_q.jpg"/>
    </button>
 </nav>
</nav>
    <header class="headerr row">

        <div class="col-md-6" style="border:3px solid #F00;">

            <img src="http://localhost/teleprintblog/assets/img/logo.png" 
                 class="img-responsive" alt="logo"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6" style="border:3px solid #F00;">

        </div>

    </header>


    <section class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-offset-1" 
             style="border:3px solid #00F;z-index:3;position:relative;">
            asdasda
        </div>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

The UI is not appearing properly for the nav-bar although I've loaded the required files.What is causing the problem ?

I've copied the `navbar` code from [here](http://metroui.org.ua/navbar.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
<nav class="navigation-bar dark fixed">
```

To:

```
<nav class="navigation-bar dark fixed-top"> <!-- Or fixed-bottom -->
```

---

As stated in the [documentation](http://metroui.org.ua/navbar.html):

> You can create fixed (top or bottom) navigation bar with built in subclasses `**.fixed-top**, .**fixed-bottom**.

Comment: that did not made any difference :( same result

Comment: You're also missing the `.metro` class on your body.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with Metro Bootstrap UI CSS  aka http://metroui.org.ua/ is this:

You load the theme to localhost, or mabe into a MCV framework, and the dropdown doesnt work! Right?

Okay so look for this line in the html file

```
<script src="js/load-metro.js"></script>
```

This is where the problem is.

You can open this file and see the contents - its best to use a full url to include the JS files. I myself removed this line from my files:

```
<script src="js/load-metro.js"></script>
```

And I replaced it with the contents:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    if ((document.location.host.indexOf('.dev') > -1) || (document.location.host.indexOf('modernui') > -1) ) {
        $("<script/>").attr('src', '<?=base_url('adminstyle')?>/js/metro/metro-loader.js').appendTo($('head'));
    } else {
        $("<script/>").attr('src', '<?=base_url('adminstyle')?>/js/metro.min.js').appendTo($('head'));
    }
})
</script>
```

now you will notice I use `base_url()` - this is for my case only. Replace that with your full url and walla the dropdown should be working.